# TypeReference with generic parameter to deserialize list of objects

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that return data from an application, where methods point to different endpoint and return different objects, for example:

```
public List<Cat> getCats() {
    String url = this.BASE_URL + "/cats";
    return getDataFromAPI(url, new TypeReference<List<Cat>>() {});
}

public List<Dog> getDogs() {
    String url = this.BASE_URL + "/dogs";
    return getDataFromAPI(url, new TypeReference<List<Dog>>() {});
}

public <T> T getDataFromAPI(String url, TypeReference<T> typeRef) {
   //restTemplate is Spring RestTemplate
   Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> response = 
this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class);

   //objectMapper is Jackson ObjectMapper
   return this.objectMapper.convertValue(response.get("response"), typeReference);
}
```

I would like to improve my code and only send two simple parameters, for example: `getCats` and `getDogs` only send the raw type to `getDataFromAPI`... something like:

```
public List<Cat> getCats() {
    String url = this.BASE_URL + "/cats";
    return getDataFromAPI(url, Cat); //i know it doesnt work
}

public <T> T getDataFromAPI(String url, T type) {

   Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> response =
 this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class);

   return this.mapper.convertValue(response.get("response"), 
new TypeReference<List<type>>() {}); //pass the type dynamically
}
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. Following code will work:

```
public List<Cat> getCats() {
    String url = this.BASE_URL + "/cats";
    return getDataFromAPI(url, Cat.class);
}

public <T extends Object> List<T> getDataFromAPI(String url, Class<T> type) {

    Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> response =
            this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class);

    return this.mapper.convertValue(response.get("response"), 
            new TypeReference<List<type>>() {}); //pass the type dynamically
}
```

Since, I am not sure what restTemplate and mapper is so I have written a small program of my own to check if it works. Here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(callFriend("duck", Duck.class));
}

static HashMap<String, List> x = new HashMap<>();
static{
    x.put(
            "dog", new ArrayList<Dog>(){
                {add(new Dog());add(new Dog());}
                });
    x.put(
            "duck", new ArrayList<Duck>(){
                {add(new Duck());add(new Duck());}
                });
}

public static <T> List<T> callFriend(String name, Class<T> type) {
    return x.get(name);
}
```

Feel free to modify the code and play around. Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: it doesnt work. `type` used to instance `TypeReference<List<type>>` is unknown. Also, parameter `Class<T> type` is not a valid parameter to `Duck.class`.

Your `callFriend` method is not using `type` parameter.